# Remove comma after click the submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was trying to remove comma from all of my input before submit to my database using below method :

```html
<form method="POST" class="form-horizontal  mb-5" onsubmit="submitForm()">
    <input type="text" name="Salary" class="textInput form-control commanumber">
    <input type="text" name="Bonus" class="textInput form-control commanumber">
    <input type="text" name="Overtime" class="textInput form-control commanumber">
        ....
</form>
```

```js
function submitForm() {
    var input = $('.commanumber');
    input.val(input.val().replace(/,/g, ''));
}
```

I managed to remove the comma and store it in my database but the problem is it converts all of the inputs to the same value. Now all of my inputs have the Salary value.

May I know how can I remove the comma from all of my `.commanumber` input properly and store it in the database?

Comment: Why don't you treat the values directly in your backend before submitting them?

Comment: your `input` variable is an array of elements, if you need to change each element individually you need something like `input.forEach( field => { ... })`

Comment: `input.prop('value', function (idx, val) {return val.replace(/,/g, '');});` does the trick. @cloned `input` variable is not an array, it's a jQuery object.

Comment: ah, missed the jquery part. Just wanted to give a pointer in the right direction. and it's still an array, just with jquery objects. since there are multiple inputs with this class.

Comment: @cloned Again, it's not an array, it's a jQuery object. JQuery object contains properties named with numbers (among other properties), it partially behaves like an array, but doesn't have the methods of arrays, ex. `input.forEach()` would trigger an error in this case.

Comment: yeah you are right :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your input variable is an array of elements, so you need to select one by one in order to remove commas. I'm providing you 3 ways to do it :

```js
function submitForm(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.commanumber').each((index, input) => { //1st way
      const $input = $(input);
      $input.val($input.val().replace(/,/g, ''));
  });
  
  let input = document.querySelectorAll('.commanumber'); //2nd way
  input.forEach(index => {
      $(index).val($(index).val().replace(/,/g, ''));
  });
  
  $.map(input, function(content, i) { //3rd way
      $(content).val($(content).val().replace(/,/g, ''));
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="POST" class="form-horizontal  mb-5" onsubmit="submitForm(event)">
    <input type="text" name="Salary" class="textInput form-control commanumber" value="8,210,010">
    <input type="text" name="Bonus" class="textInput form-control commanumber" value="1,058,543">
    <input type="text" name="Overtime" class="textInput form-control commanumber" value="16,789">
    <input type="submit" value="Remove Commas!" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than select all elements, you need to select one by one individually by `jQuery.each` method.

```js
function submitForm(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // remove this in your project!
  $('.commanumber').each((index, input) => {
    const $input = $(input);
    $input.val($input.val().replace(/,/g, ''));
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="POST" class="form-horizontal  mb-5" onsubmit="submitForm(event)">
  <input type="text" name="Salary" class="textInput form-control commanumber" value="1,234,567">
  <input type="text" name="Bonus" class="textInput form-control commanumber" value="200,000">
  <input type="text" name="Overtime" class="textInput form-control commanumber" value="300,000">
  <input type="submit" value="Remove Commas!" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should give your inputs different Id's or class names

```js
btn=document.getElementById("btn")

btn.addEventListener("click",(e)=>{
e.preventDefault() // you should remove this if use this code in your project
submitForm()
})
function submitForm() {
    var input = $('#salary');
    var input1 = $('#bonus');
     console.log("before salary",input.val())
     console.log("before bonus",input1.val())

    input.val(input.val().replace(/,/g, ''));
    input1.val(input1.val().replace(/,/g, ''));
        console.log("after",input.val())
        console.log("after",input1.val())

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="POST" class="form-horizontal  mb-5" onsubmit="submitForm()">
    <input type="text" name="Salary" id="salary" class="textInput form-control commanumber">
    <input type="text" name="Bonus" id="bonus" class="textInput form-control commanumber">
    <input type="text" name="Overtime" class="textInput form-control commanumber">
      <input type="submit" name="submit" id="btn">

</form>
```